# How to find active AWS services so I won't be billed?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I received a mail from AWS saying my free tier is going to expire at the end of this month, ok fine.

Now, after some research I found out that I can see all my active services with the tag editor (https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/resource-groups/tag-editor) by selecting "All regions" and "All available resources") so yesterday I deleted anything one by one region by region and now, checking my bills just to be sure I found out I have like 8 pages of a PDF file while yesterday there were just a few rows.

How should I really check if I will not billed nothing after my trial expires?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you access the **AWS Cost Explorer** (from the main menu) and click **Cost Explorer**.

You can then view costs **by Service**:

[image: AWS Costs by Service]

You can also go into the **Bills** section, which breaks-down usage by service and tells you what caused the charge:

[image: AWS Billing]

Comment: Honestly i can't figure out what's going on in the cost explorer. Should i close the account? I think i will be billed anyway even if i close it

Comment: Can you add a picture from the **Bills** section to your Question? We should be able to assist.

Comment: Thanks, i made a screenshot of the whole page, i hope it helps. https://imgur.com/a/sQ6SbAk

Comment: I don't think that any of the services listed will cost you any money. I suggest you repeat the exercise next month and see whether something incurs a cost. If it did, it would only be a few cents.

Comment: Is it possible that all these costs are there just because they are request for deactivating all active services? They appeared after i made that operations

Answer (score -1):

[image: AWS Free Tier]

Please select trails as updated in image, so it lists services which are free and also its expiry date. So that these services will be free and not be charged until the mentioned limit of data usage.

Comment: Which section is that? I can't find it

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=*all&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=categories%23compute&trk=fb8718a7-d9f7-4e07-9fc5-b85de26b4178&sc_channel=ps&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!476942607286!b!!g!!%2Baws%20%2Bcloud&ef_id=Cj0KCQjwhY-aBhCUARIsALNIC04w5gXPJEov_TGZCEPtht_U8fqaLAMiPuym6PrWEk39Pr_-xAP-bvUaAne7EALw_wcB:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!476942607286!b!!g!!%2Baws%20%2Bcloud

Comment: Please go through the above link.There You can select trails/always free/12 months free....It shows the list of free services